# Wiki markup language with excellent table support

Tags: python, wiki-markup

I'm developing a wiki with Python/Django, partly for educational purposes. Up to now I'm still missing the right markup language. I tried quite a view, including Creole and Markdown, which worked well except for the table support. Common wiki markup languages seem to support only rudimentary tables, i.e. a single line per cell or no complex markups within cells. But the users of my wiki want to be able to create tables with bigger formatet text and lists within the cells. I have my problems with finding a markup language which actually can do this.

I've gazed upon the MediaWiki markup language which seems to support everything but I think using this would be overkill. The rest of the markup can be quite simple with focus on easy-writability of markup (I find MediaWiki markup somewhat ugly sometimes). Furthermore, there must be a Python module for translating markup into HTML which I can use in the webapp. I'm still looking for one for MediaWiki markup.

Another alternative would be to dump wiki markup languages at all and instead allow a set of defined HTML tags for markup. But that makes it harder to write wiki articles, since HTML is not invented for such use. and also finding and escaping forbidden HTML could be quite tricky. I would rather have a nice markup language with a lightweight Python implementation.

Does anyone know of a markup language with extended table support and an implementation in Python which I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution myself since I found reST to complicated to use for technically inexperienced users. I might be a bit elaborate but it works for me.

The key is an extension for an already existing markup language. I found Markdown rather pleasant, despite its lack of table support. Using Python-Markdown, [here](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Writing_Extensions) is everything you need to know for writing your own extension. It's not that complicated. I hacked something together in half an hour and it actually works so far. I would show the code here but I'm not really proud of it yet ;) Basically, you parse a markup block and insert the table elements in the DOM as you like.

I guess every usable implementation of a markup language should have some kind of extension mechanism, so it should be possible to write extensions for other languages and implementations, too. That's not the most convenient solution but still better than using some ugly language just for the feature's sake.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it meats your needs, but you could use [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).  [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) generates html from it for the python documentation and its written in python, so it should be easy to use for this purpose.  I find it very neat and easy to read, as its designed to be, and it can do quite complicated tables.

Comment: I suppose the exact definition of a markup language is a bit varied, so I don't know if `rest` does technically fall into this category, but its easy to write, easy to read and compiles to good-looking html, so its probably quite a good candidate for this sort of usage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. reST does indeed support everything I need and has even integration in Django. However, I don't find it that easy to read for non-techies and even harder too write, if you look at the actual markup for a complex table. At least, I would'nt like being forced to adapt the whole column if one cell has grown a little. I would like to know how Python developers do that ;) Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Yes, complex tables are a bit tricky, but so far I have never actually needed to use one.  The only reason for using a complex table rather than a simple one is if the first column needs to be wordwrapped, which for me just never happens.